# How to fix error with period in error in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I have the following javascript that takes 2 variables (chapterid and txt) and uses them as parameters in a url.  'txt' is derived from a user selection.

My problem: when the user selection has a period in it, the routes.rb file has issues matching the url or might ignore everything after period.

Example:

routes.rb

```
match "readers/chapannotations/new/:chapterid/:selection/"  => "readers#newchapannotation"
```

javascript

```
      url = '/readers/chapannotations/new/' + chapterid + '/' + txt + '/';
      console.log(url);
      window.location = url;


txt = 'O Arjuna.'
URL that opens: http://mysite.com/readers/chapannotations/new/5/O%20Arjuna./
```

This leads to no url being opened as there isn't one that matches in routes.rb.  I believe this is because of the "." at th end of txt.

txt = 'O Arjuna'
   http://mysite.com/readers/chapannotations/new/5/O%20Arjuna/

This url opens just fine, I believe because there is no period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in your `routes.rb`:

```
match "readers/chapannotations/new/:chapterid/:selection/"  => "readers#newchapannotation", :selection => /.*/
```

Comment: I still get an error when I select text with period saying it doesn't match.

Comment: What is your rails version? I've tested it here and worked perfectly on rails 3.2.13

Comment: Hmm that's odd, I have the same version too.

Comment: Try this `match "readers/chapannotations/new/:chapterid/:selection/"  => "readers#newchapannotation", :constraints => { :selection => /.*/ }` and restart your server (it should not be necessary but it worth the try)